# EF6 Model First: schema specified is not valid, error 0040

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, localdb, ef-model-first

I see that this question has been asked quite a bit, but none of the solutions have helped me since I'm using model first and not code first.

I have a C# project in VS 2015 using EF6.  I am building a database using the model first approach and can successfully generate the SQL code from the model and run it in SSMS.  I'm using SQL Server LocalDB.

The problem I have is that whenever I try to add a programmatically created entity to the collection (table) to which it belongs, I always get the error

*An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code*

*Additional information: Schema specified is not valid.*

*Errors: 
Market.ssdl(184,6) : error 0040: The Type nvarchar(max) is not qualified with a namespace or alias. Only primitive types can be used without qualification.*

The entity I'm creating is has only one property; a string (or nvarchar(max) in the database).  Again, I can create the object, but the moment I try to add it to its collection (or table) before saving any changes, I get the above error.  I even tried not naming the Name property, but the error persists.

`using (var context = new MarketContainer())
    {
        // Create data source
        var datasource = new DataSource()
        {
            Name = dataSourceName
        };
        // Save data source
        context.DataSources.Add(datasource);
    }`

Another SO answer proposed to right click on the .tt file and clicking "Run Custom Tool", but that didn't do anything.

I tried this once with MySQL and it worked fine! Now that I need to move to SQL Server it doesn't work...  I've been stuck on this problem for over a week, so really any help would go a long way.

Comment: Do you have a diagram?

Comment: I resolved the issue (see my answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has been resolved.  I was referencing the project which contained the entity model from another project, and the App.configs were not matching.  Once I copied the contents from the entity project's config file to the referencing project's, everything began working properly.

Hopefully this helps someone other than myself!